# Intersection of conditions

Tags: list-manipulation

If I have a list of conditions:

```
{cond1,cond2,cond3}
```

and I want to use an `If[]` statement to test the intersection of these conditions (or, more generally, any subset of them, but let's start with the basic case first):

```
If[cond1&&cond2&&cond3,a,b]
```

How would I do that?

Comment: Something like `conds = {cond1, cond2, cond3}; If[And @@ conds, a, b]`?

Comment: Yes. Thanks J.M. I feel like I'm asking lots of quite trivial questions, but I have yet to get a feel for the syntax, and haven't got a good idea yet of what I need to search for in the documentation to find what I need.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't worry about whether these are trivial questions: they are good opportunities to explain a little more about Mathematica's syntax.

The first point is that what you already had works fine. You can confirm this using `FullForm`.

```
If[cond1 && cond2 && cond3, a, b] // FullForm
(*If[And[cond1,cond2,cond3],a,b]*)
```

If you preferred, you could type out the `And` construction explicitly.

J.M.'s comment invokes the `Apply` function to change the `Head` of a `List` of things, in this case the conditions, to `And`.

```
And @@ {cond1, cond2, cond3} // FullForm
(* And[cond1,cond2,cond3] *)
```

Or equivalently

```
FullForm[Apply[And, {cond1, cond2, cond3}]]
(* And[cond1,cond2,cond3] *)
```

The `FullForm` is just for explication; you wouldn't use it in normal operations. So the short syntax for the above is:

```
And @@ {cond1, cond2, cond3}
(* cond1&&cond2&&cond3 *)
```

The usefulness of storing your list of conditions *as* a list is that it is then easier to use various other list-manipulation techniques to get those subsets of conditions mentioned in your question.

```
And @@ (Most@{cond1, cond2, cond3})
(* cond1&&cond2 *)
```